# How to create a table in redshift cluster via boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, boto

We have a use case, where we have multiple cluster in our AWS account, in one of them we want to create a table with a schema

```
( 
    marketplaceId    integer ,
    cohort    varchar(90) ,
    segment    varchar(90) ,
    eventName    varchar(90) ,
    propensity_bin_id    integer ,
    run_date    varchar(90) ,
    model_version    integer ,
    customer_id    numeric(38,0) ,
    event_date    date ,
    role    varchar(90) ,
    dsi_split    varchar(90) ,
    target_metric    varchar(90) ,
    horizon    varchar(90) ,
    actual_target_value    numeric(38,5) ,
    predicted_baseline_value    numeric(38,5) ,
    predicted_treatment_value    numeric(38,5) ,
    winsorized_residual_value    numeric(38,5) ,
    residual_variance    numeric(38,5) ,
    is_valid    integer ,
    run_id    varchar(90) ,
    occurrence    varchar(90)  
 );
```

Can we create this table via boto client, I am unable to find any documentation for the same. Any help on this would be super helpful

Comment: Boto3 provides the Redshift Data API service, which lets you execute SQL queries. The documentation should tell you everything you need to know. If you have specific questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

To perform this you will need to issue the SQL command CREATE TABLE and since you want to do this through boto (not a JDBC or ODBC connection to the database) you will need to set up Redshift Data API.  See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html

and the boto3 information about using it at:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html

Redshift CREATE TABLE reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html

Be aware that to use Redshift Data API you will need to configure you cluster to enable it and set up the correct roles and permissions in IAM.